# Can I change background color only for some instances of a class?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I use two instances of jQuery tabs defined by id **tabs** & **tabs2**

The class that defines color of the tabs background is called **ui-widget-header**

Can I somehow change the background color for the second tab **tabs2**? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/wbjZS/)

[image]

HTML
    
        
            results
            textarea

CSS

```
.ui-widget-header {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #F6A828;
    border: 1px solid #E78F08;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}


    <div id="tabs2-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"> 
<div style="overflow:auto;height:600px" id="results"></div></div>
<div id="tabs2-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">    </div>

</div>
```

I tried

```
#tabs2 > .ui-widget-header {background-color: blue;}
```

and

```
#tabs2.ui-widget-header {background-color: blue;}
```

but none worked

Comment: Does that class belong to the #tabs2 element, a direct child element, or any element within?

Comment: maybe you can show the structure of your html

Comment: #tabs2.ui-widget-header {background-color: blue;}
should work nice on "<div id='tabs2' class='ui-widget-header'>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update, for jQuery-UI:**

It is not enough to set the background color, you must also remove the background image that jQuery-UI uses.

So, this:

```
#tabs2 {
    background-color: powderBlue;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Produces this:

[image: Base BG color change]

But I'm going to guess that you want more like this:

[image: Fancier BG color change]

Which requires more elaborate CSS:

```
#tabs3 {
    background-color: powderBlue;
    background-image: none;
}
#tabs3 .ui-tabs, #tabs3 .ui-tabs-panel, 
#tabs3 .ui-tabs-selected, #tabs3 .ui-tabs-selected a {
    background-color: powderBlue;
    background-image: none;
}
```

[**See it at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wbjZS/2/)

---

---

**Old answer, for the generic question:**

Based on the newly pasted HTML,

```
#tabs2 ul.ui-widget-header {background-color: blue;}
```

Should do the trick.

If not, one of these should work:

```
#tabs2 {background-color: blue!important;}
#tabs2 ul {background-color: blue!important;}
#tabs2 {background-color: blue;}
#tabs2 ul.ui-widget-header {background-color: blue!important;}
```

Comment: @Rikudo: That spaced enough for you?

Comment: That's not what I meant. `#tabs2 { background-color: blue !important; }`

Comment: @Rikudo: YGBFSM.  Do you have any professional style guides that **requires** such inanity?

Comment: Nope, nothing that requires it, but for minimal code readability sake, at least I think that those extra 2 bytes are needed.

Comment: @Rikudo: That's good, but that is your highly subjective opinion.  One that is not shared by any coder or company I've yet to work with/for.

Comment: @BrockAdams let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2397/discussion-between-rikudo-sennin-and-brock-adams)

Comment: @Radek: Something is missing.  Please do one or more of the following: (1) Link to the page in question if possible. (2) Make an example, that shows the problem, at http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ . (3) Otherwise, save the page's HTML and CSS at pastebin.com and link to that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have realized it was a jQuery-UI situation sooner.  Anyway, see the updated answer.

Comment: Brock. Thank you for your patience :-) Please see my updated jsfiddle. I am after the blue background. http://jsfiddle.net/radek/wbjZS/3/ that is defined by `.ui-widget-header {background: blue;}` But I want the change to be only for one #tabs not tabs1 or tabs2.

Comment: Then you would use `#tabs .ui-widget-header {background: blue;}`. See http://jsfiddle.net/wbjZS/4/ .

Comment: Wow. So all I need is `#tabs .ui-widget-header {background: blue;}` but `#tabs .ui-widget-header {background-color: blue;}` doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, remember that there is a BG image you must block. The former does that, `background-color` leaves the BG image alone.

Answer (score 1):

If the element is not a direct descendant of `#tabs2` none of the codes you posted will work. The first one for obvious reasons (because it has to be a direct descendant for it to work),

And **the second one is because a syntax error**.

```
#tabs2.ui-widget-header {background-color: blue;}
```

instead of

```
#tabs2 .ui-widget-header {background-color: blue;}
```

(note the space).

Also, if that doesn't work too, you should try using `!important` to make sure your rules override any other rules.

Comment: Please note that your first example is NOT a syntax error, the first selector will select the `#tabs2` element so long as it has the `.ui-widget-header` class.

Comment: I never said the first one is a syntax error, THE SECOND ONE is, I'll update my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You need add at last `background-image: none;` like this:

```
#tabsAdmin .ui-widget-header {    
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 5px ; 
  background-color: #7BA4C1;     
  background-image: none;
}
```